# Adding JavaScript List to the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, dom

In class, our assignment was to create a grocery list of fruit and their prices by placing objects into an array. Now that I did that part, i'm supposed to Extend the shopping cart program from the last lab. Set up a basic HTML page
Append the items and their prices from the shopping list to the page."
This is where I got lost. We can only use vanilla JavaScript. ** I was able to get the webpage to display the total button, and it works(it calculated the items), but where is my list of groceries and their prices?!

my code:

```
var fruita = {
name: 'apple',
price: 5
};

var fruitb = {
name: 'pear',
price:3
};

var fruitc = {
name: 'orange',
price: 4
};

var grocery = [];
grocery.push(fruita, fruitb, fruitc);


var total = (fruita.price + fruitb.price +fruitc.price);

for (i=0; i<grocery.length; i++){
console.log(grocery[i].name);
console.log(grocery[i].price);
}

var total = (fruita.price + fruitb.price +fruitc.price);
console.log("total price= " + total);

function calcTotal() {
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
}

function displayList() {
document.write(grocery).innerHTML = grocery;
```

In my html:

```
<head>
<script src="monday2assn2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<h1> Shopping List </h1>

<p>Click "Total" to add up your shopping list.</p>


<button onclick="calcTotal()">Total</button>

<p id="total"> </p>
```

Comment: Read through the documentation for Document.createElement() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement and Node.appendChild(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild, then give it a try. If you still need help, edit your question to include your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

One good way to start is to create a global function that standardizes your method for adding elements to the page. Here are functions that can be used to add an element to a parent element:

```
function addElement(type,content,parent) {
    var newElement = document.createElement(type);
    var newContent = document.createTextNode(content);
    newElement.appendChild(newContent);
    get(parent,'id');
    current.insertBefore(newElement,current.childNodes[0]);
}
function get(reference, type) {
    switch(type) {
        case 'id':
        current = document.getElementById(reference);
        break;
        case 'class':
        current = document.getElementsByClassName(reference);
        break;
        case 'tag':
        current = document.getElementsByTagName(reference);
        break;
    }
}
```

I copied and pasted this from my own files, as I use these frequently. The *get* function is used to select elements. The *addElement* function is used to create a new element. The "type" parameter specifies the tag - so p, div, span, etc. "Content" and "parent" are pretty straightforward. The "parent" parameter is represented by the id of the parent. Once done, you can do something as so:

```
for(var i=0;i<grocery.length;i++) {
    var concat = 'Item: ' + grocery[i].name + ' Price: ' + grocery[i].price;
    addElement('p',concat,'body'); //assign the body tag an id of "body"
}
```

An alternate method is to simply set the innerHTML of the body to add everything to it.

```
get('body','id');
var joined = current.innerHTML; //all elements in a string
for(var i=0;i<grocery.length;i++) {
    var concat = 'Item: ' + grocery[i].name + ' Price: ' + grocery[i].price;
    joined += concat;
}
current.innerHTML = joined;
```

Of course, it would help if you'd specify more specifically how exactly you want your data to be formatted in the HTML. But don't fear Vanilla Javascript - I find it to be much easier than using libraries for things like this, and people often become too reliant on libraries that they forget the roots of JS.